# Moving minecraft mods from old Mac to new Mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, macos

I have an old Macbook with Minecraft 1.5.2.
I have several dozen mods I use daily.
I just got a new Macbook Pro and downloaded the Minecraft app.
It works fine.

But I need my mods.
So I went to the old Mac's Library- Application Support-  Minecraft folder and copied it all to an external drive.  I then loaded all those files from the external drive to the same location on the new Macbook.  But when I run Minecraft the mods do not work.

When I moved the files from the desktop of the new Mac to the Application Support folder, the error box said Application Support cannot be modified.  So I went to the folder permissions and changed them to Read and Write.  The files are now able to be moved, but are still not working.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I notice you haven't mentioned installing a modloader (such as Forge or ModLoader) in the new Minecraft on the new Mac. Without one, Minecraft will never try to load your mods. Have you installed one and just forgot to mention that in your question?

Comment: Also: Which version of Minecraft is the new Mac running? Unless you've picked 1.5.2 from the profile editor it's probably 1.6.2, which will not work with your 1.5.2 mods even after installing a modloader. You have to make sure the versions match by running 1.5.2 and installing a 1.5.2 modloader.

Answer (score 1):

> the error box said Application Support cannot be modified

The Application Support folder in `~/Library/` should *always be able to be written to* (without asking for special permission) by the user, however the Application Support folder in `/Library/` should not. If you try to copy the files to `/Library/`, it will ask for permission, an indication that something's wrong.

I know you said you are copying them to the same location, but still, make sure you are copying the files to your **personal Application Support folder `~/Library/Application Support/`**. If you copy the files to the global Application Support folder in `/Library/`, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

1) Open Finder, press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and paste this:

```
~/Library/Application Support/
```

2) Find the folder called `minecraft`.

3) Right click it and press "Compress"

4) Copy it to a flash disk.

5) Connect the flash disk to your new Mac, open Finder and type the same thing.

6) Drag the compressed file there

7) Right click it and press "Uncompress" (or Unzip).